# Inherit Twin Settings in Deployments - Azure IoT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Is there a way to make edge module twin settings in Azure IoT deployments inheritable?

For instance I have dozens of devices with dozens of module twin configuration settings. I want 95% of the twin settings to be the same across all devices defined in a single deployment. But I also need to set a small number of device/location specific twin settings on each device.

So far my testing shows the deployment will overwrite all module twin settings. And a deployment with higher priority will overwrite all other module twin settings. My ideal scenario would be some kind of inheritable relationship where a 2nd deployment would add to the master deployment settings. Is anything like this possible? What are the best practices for this scenario?

Comment: This is not possible as of today.
You will have to generate your deployments.

Comment: @Zied does MS offer some tooling to automate the generation? Doing it manually is going to be a tedious process and as far as I can tell the IoT hub user interface only allows export of deployments, no way to import a deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure IoT Edge provides two ways to configure the modules to run on IoT Edge devices: one for development and fast iterations on a single device, and one for managing large fleets of IoT Edge devices. Both of these approaches are available in the Azure portal and programmatically.

Source: [Understand IoT Edge automatic deployments for single devices or at scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-deployment-monitoring)

You will need to follow best practices and create IotEdge deployments and "store" them on the respective IoTHub so that you can edit them after. Changes to IoT Edge deployment manifest are not incremental, therefore when deploying a manifest you need to enumerate all modules + the new one.